# wamp server showing orange icon?

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I have upgraded my php version from 5.5.12 to 7.1.2 from this link [Check the link here](http://www.web-technology-experts-notes.in/2015/06/how-to-upgrade-php-53-to-php-54-in-wamp-server-in-window7.html)

But when i start my wamp server it is showing orange icon

Then i checked `apache > service > install service`

At the command prompt it is displaying : `Your port 80 is available..Install will proceed
Press Enter to Proceed.`

But the icon stays orange. Any solution??

Comment: try rechecking your port defined in httpd.conf, search keyword listen and check the port defined there, also  Ensure you have the Visual C++ Redistributable Package for Visual Studio 2012 installed. 

if doesnt work please elaborate your question. Was it working before the update ?

Comment: is it necessary to install Visual C++ Redistributable Package for Visual Studio 2012??

Comment: Yes it requires some .dll files to run the service

Comment: how to check whether i have installed visual studio 2012??

Comment: Have you considered upgrading to WAMPServer 3 here is a useful post [on the WAMPServer forum on how to safely upgrade](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606) and here is a [All you need to know about WAMPServer 3 post](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my answer is I installed the latest wamp server and then followed all the requirements needed for the PHP version 7.

Comment: would you please try to explain this?

Comment: @Ahsan just install the latest wamp server